# The name "covid" doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2019

Hi i convert sql query to linq i got this error. when i remove group by there isn't exception but i should use group by. why i got this exception ?

```cs
public List<BiontechSinovacCovidDto> GetBiontechSinovacCovidDto()
{
    using(SirketDBContext context=new SirketDBContext())
    {
        var result = 
            from asi in context.Asilar
            join covid in context.Covids
                on asi.CovidId equals covid.CovidId
            group asi by asi.AsiIsmi into isim
            select new BiontechSinovacCovidDto
            {
                AsiIsmi=isim.Key,
    //exception    OrtalamaCovidSuresi=(EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(covid.CovidYakalanmaTarih, covid.CovidBitisTarih)).Average()
            };
        return result.ToList();                                              
    }
}
```

my sql query

```sql
Select 
    AsiIsmi,
    AVG(Cast(DATEDIFF(Day,CovidYakalanmaTarih, CovidBitisTarih)AS FLOAT)) as OrtalamaCovidSuresi 
From Asilar 
    INNER JOIN Covids on Covids.CovidId=Asilar.CovidId 
group by AsiIsmi
```

```
|AsiIsmi| OrtalamaCovidSuresi|
-------  ------------------
Biontech      13.6667
Sinovac        15
```

BiontechSinovacCovidDto

```cs
public class BiontechSinovacCovidDto
{
    public string AsiIsmi { get; set; }
    public double OrtalamaCovidSuresi { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please first try to get the C# model right. You don't need `join` nor `group by` if you have navigation properties. What does the class model look like now and what are you using, I guess Entity Framework, and which version?

Comment: yes entity framework 3.1 verison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Average` has overload which accepts lambda. You have to use this version. Also you have to group `covid` in this case.

```cs
public List<BiontechSinovacCovidDto> GetBiontechSinovacCovidDto()
{
    using (var context = new SirketDBContext())
    {
        var result = 
            from asi in context.Asilar
            join covid in context.Covids
                on asi.CovidId equals covid.CovidId
            group covid by asi.AsiIsmi into isim
            select new BiontechSinovacCovidDto
            {
                AsiIsmi = isim.Key,
                OrtalamaCovidSuresi = isim.Average(x => EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.CovidYakalanmaTarih, x.CovidBitisTarih))
            };

        return result.ToList();                                              
    }
}
```

Comment: probably instead of g be isim because if i wrote "g.Average" got exception from G.average